# Werewolf romance with one evocative line

Tags: story-identification, werewolf, romantic-interest

Trying to track this one down...  Here is what I know.

- Paranormal romance book, featuring werewolves as good guys instead of evil monsters
- Heroine is a werewolf, but not a tough gal
- Heroine has a tough guy following her around trying to protect her; she makes life difficult for him.  Sometimes this is by accident
- Tough guy is a werewolf too
- It's a romance, so everyone is super-pretty or studly handsome
- A bit more ... *prim* than your typical romance.  Werewolves are bonded for life with their first werewolf lover, so are often quite chaste

And one line which I (think I) remember; danger is near, heroine takes a look at herself and ruefully says something very like:  "I don't know what this body is made for, but fighting ain't it"

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible the Mercy series by Patricia Briggs? She fits the bill, and so does Adam (her protector) https://www.goodreads.com/series/40932-mercy-thompson

Comment: Can you explain why you feel this answer is correct?

Comment: It fits every aspect of the bill, including mercy's personality. She was raised by werewolves but is meeker.

Comment: :) Then add that to your answer. Preferably, also link to some place that has it and/or add a summary.

Comment: Appreciate the answer!  Isn't Mercy, because I followed the links and these aren't books I've read, but they do look interesting.